# How to disable OneSignal on android?

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I want to use `OneSignal` on my app to send notifications to my users, and it is well documented and good, you should just act like this:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
    .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
    .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
    .init();
```

The problem is, I want to just send notification to my logged in users, so if a user logged out, I dont want him to receive notification, how can I disable `OneSignal` after it's inited?

I don't want to handle this on server, it should be some way to stop `OneSignal` service, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the following method in the logout process.

```
OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
```

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--setsubscription-

**EDIT 2022:**

// RN SDK version 4.x.x

```
OneSignal.disablePush(true);
```

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sdk-reference#disablepush-method

Answer (score 5):

We can easily enable/disable the `OneSignal` push notification using the below method:

```
OneSignal.disablePush(boolean)
```

Source:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sdk-reference#disablepush-method

Answer (score 3):

OneSignal has something called segments... (flags).

You can set a flag with OneSignal. If the user is logged in, they belong to a flag that logged out users don't.

For example, if logged in, set a flag for OneSignal as *loggedin*. If logged out, set the flag for OneSignal for this user as *loggedout*. When you send out notifications, you only send it to the *loggedin* flag.

Comment: This will help, but is not the exact thing i want, a want a way to completely disable and unregister the device, exact oposite of "init"

Comment: From what I have read, no, this is not possible. Perhaps you should drop onesignal a line, they usually get back within a few days.

Answer (score 2):

### SOLUTION 2023: after the version [5.0.0, 5.99.99]

---

### Disable Push:

```
OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.optOut()
```

### Enable Push:

```
OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.optIn()
```

---

### PS. Vel_daN: Love what You DO .

---